# Send email upon publish/unpublish of an item in custom component

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component, overrides, emails

I have created a hello world component based upon this documentation https://docs.joomla.org/Special:MyLanguage/J3.2:Developing_an_MVC_Component/

I want to send a notification to users if an item's publishing status has been changed.

I found the function `listItemTask`. 
 Can we override this function in my custom component?

Comment: Welcome Zack.  While you wait for support, please take the [tour] and perhaps peruse the existing pages that share the same tags as your question.  Please continue trying to self-solve.  If you make progress, you are welcome to edit your question to express exactly where you are stuck.  When asking development questions it is often helpful to show the pertinent portion of your script where you would like help (not someone else's hello world, but _your_ script).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you look at creating a plugin to send the email that responds to a onContentChangeState event trigger. The plugin would check that it is an item of your component being changed($context in the params) and then it will provide the ID and the value(Published/Unplublished) that you can use in your email subject or body.

This should be a starting point for you, https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content, third from the bottom.